# accessing dictionary key and value with one key in a tuple

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary with tuples as key and a value like this:

```
dic = {('1/1/2016', '00:00'): data1,
       ('1/1/2016', '00:05'): data2,
       ('2/1/2016', '00:00'): data3}
```

I would like to access all the keys and values with only providing the first element of tuple (the date) without looping on all the data in dictionary. Is there any way to do that without too much processing?

Comment: No. Finding a value by the first element of the tuple, in that data structure as you've given it, cannot be performed in sub-linear time.

Comment: use nested dictionaries with the time being in the second level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As recommended by AlexHall and Antti Haapala, using nested dictionary solves the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could loop through it once, and create a new dictionary, then you can look up the data as you need it.

```
dic = {('1/1/2016', '00:00'): 1,
       ('1/1/2016', '00:05'): 2,
       ('2/1/2016', '00:00'): 3}

new_dict = {}
for item in dic.items():
    key = item[0][0]
    new_dict.setdefault(key,[])
    new_dict[key].append(item)
```

Comment: 1) `setdefault` returns the value, so `new_dict.setdefault(key,[]).append(item)` will do (and since `key` only appears once now, it can be inlined). 2) Even better: `new_dict = defaultdict(list)` and `new_dict[key].append(item)`. 3) This loses the ability to look up by time. A nested dictionary with the time as a second key would be more usable.

Comment: @AlexHall  I considered 1 and 2, but went this route for readability, and no imports.    As for 3, you're absolutely right, but that wasn't really the question.